# tableofcontents too large

Tags: beamer, spacing, table-of-contents

I would like to insert `\tableofcontents[currentsection]` in my presentation. Unfortunately I have not so many sections, so the space between the "items" is too much.
I don't wont to change the `\documentclass[compress, 10pt]{beamer}` option at the beginning because otherwise it will change the dimension of all the document that is ok for me. 
Is it possible to reduce the space? And how?

Comment: You can insert your toc into a `block` environment...

Answer (score 4):

Try using `\clearpage` immediately after the table of contents. The `\clearpage` command forces everything above it to float to the top of the page in normal spacing rather than fill the page using even spacing.

Comment: works for me ! :)